# Include PHP Library on Drupal 8

Tags: php, symfony, class, drupal, drupal-8

I have a class, and I want to be able to use it on the CMS, not depending on any module, for example because I want to keep it updated by *git* and use it not only in *Drupal* projects:

```
<?php

namespace MyPackage;

class MyClass {

    public static function myFunction($message) {
        file_put_contents('./file.log', $message, FILE_APPEND);
    }

}
```

The class lives inside the libraries/ folder of the drupal website, its path being: `/libraries/MyPackage/MyClass.php`
Then I try to use it somewhere, e.g.,

```
\MyPackage\MyClass::myFunction("hey from myfunction!");
```

But the class is not reachable:

```
Error: Class 'MyPackage\MyClass' not found in ...
```

Also tried the other package path convention, placing the class in

```
/libraries/mypackage/src/MyPackage/MyClass.php
```

with no luck.

Where should I put my PHP class? Something wrong with the path? Something wrong with the naming convention? I almost tried everything, except the correct way of course.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it with

```
use MyPackage\MyClass\MyClass::myFunction("Hey from my function");
```

MyPackage\MyClass is your namespace and MyPackage\MyClass\MyClass is your full class reference.

Comment: Thank you Muhammad, I committed a typo on the question, the package was actually `namespace MyPackage;` I corrected and also tried your suggestion. Still doesn't work anyay.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the only way to do this on Drupal 8 is through the composer dependency manager, which consists of the following steps:

1. [Creating your library with composer](https://blog.jgrossi.com/2013/creating-your-first-composer-packagist-package/)
2. [Compile and upload it on Packagist](https://packagist.org)
3. [Use on your Drupal instance](https://www.morpht.com/blog/drupal-and-composer-part-4-composer-drupal-developers) as other dependencies

Comment: This is the right approach, but you can always use github, or any other VCS. All you have to do is list that under `repositories` in Drupal's composer.json and use it with `composer require`. You can even use the library without uploading it to anywhere by using it like this was. You can give local paths under `repositories`

Comment: This is interesting, I'd like to use a "local" approach. Right now I solved including the library as a module source, but I'll study this way you suggest.